# Initialising a static variable in PHP

Tags: php

Taken from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be
>   initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed.
>   So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array
>   (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a
>   function return value, or to an object.

So this means I can't do the following because a) expressions are not allowed and b) function return values are not allowed.

```
class MyClass {
    // I can't do this.
    public static $var = 10 * 2;

    // I can't do this.
    public static $sum = array_sum( array( 3, 5, 6 ) );
}
```

But, with reference to *b) function return values not allowed*, why then is it possible to do the following when `array()` is a function with a return value?

```
class MyClass {
    // I can do this.
    public static $array = array( 3, 5, 6 );
}
```

Comment: That's not a function, but a language construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array()` is not a function, it's an initializer. Unlike ordinary functions, it's interpreted at compile time, so it can be used to initialize a static.

For the reference, this is what is allowed after the `static` keyword:

```
static_scalar_value:
    common_scalar  (e.g. 42)
    static_class_name_scalar (Foo::class)
    namespace_name      (Foo)
    T_NAMESPACE T_NS_SEPARATOR namespace_name (namespace \Foo)
    T_NS_SEPARATOR namespace_name (\Foo)
    T_ARRAY '(' static_array_pair_list ')' e.g. array(1,2,3)
    '[' static_array_pair_list ']' e.g. [1,2,3]
    static_class_constant e.g. Foo::bar
    T_CLASS_C (__CLASS__)
```

http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#945

Php 5.6 adds "static operations" to this list, which makes it possible to use expressions for statics, as long as these ultimately resolve to static scalars.

```
class X {
    static $foo = 11 + (22/11); // syntax error in 5.5, valid in 5.6
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A good question! The simple ansvar is that `array()` only *looks* like a function, but in reality isn't one.

From [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php):

> Note:
>   array() is a language construct used to represent literal arrays, and not a regular function.

Answer (score -1):

Because an array is not a function.

While `array(1,2)` looks like you are calling a function that is called array, you are doing none of the sorts. You are just making an array, which is *not* a function call. it is closer to saying `$a = 1`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Well I still think it's the answer to the question

Comment: While a little more explanation would be good, I do kinda sorta agree it is going towards an anwer. Maybe the confusion comes from that `array(1,2)` maybe looks a bit like a function call?